Confusion about types (index.d.ts) and providing helpful hinting for my Node package
I have a module called 'utils'. I use JSDoc comments to provide code hinting on all my exports.
I build it using Rollup, outputting a module and a commonjs file.
This is the package.json:
{
  "name": "utils",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/utils.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/utils.cjs"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "set NODE_ENV=production && rollup -c"
  },
  "type": "module"
}

The module is uploaded to a private remote git repository.
Another project installs this module as a dependency via the git url, and I use the import statement in another script to reference it.
In VSCode, all the references to methods and variables in utils however are without hinting and untyped.
If I control+click any reference to utils, I'm taken to the esm build dist/utils.mjs, not to the source with all its types intact.
Confusion arises when I ctrl+click the names of other modules installed via npm in VSCode: I'm usually taken to an index.d.ts file either in the node_modules folder itself, or C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\5.5\node_modules\\@types\\{name_of_module}\index.d.ts
It appears some modules have types declared in a file named index.d.ts stored in the installed module directory itself, or a separate module named '@types/name_of_module' is installed by VSCode if it's available.
However, If I import my 'utils' module using an absolute path (import "/Users/me/Projects/utils"), then for some reason typing and hinting works, as it refers directly to the source file src/index.js (the "main" field in my package.json)
Ideally I would like to have the same behaviour for my npm managed version of 'utils', instead of generating index.d.ts, which I'd rather not have to deal with.
I understand this would probably be necessary for a public package but this is private.
Any ideas how I can tell VSCode to refer to the source file instead of the build when using import statements?
EDIT:
Changing my package.json's export field appeared to do the trick:
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "types": "./src/index.js",
    "import": "./dist/utils.mjs",
    "require": "./dist/utils.cjs"
  }
},

Can't find anyone else using a .js source for a "types" field online though, which suggests this is a bit hacky.
Is this the 'correct' way?

"a separate module '@types/name_of_module' is installed by VSCode if it's available." - those are third-party type declarations (not from the library authors) from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped. They won't be available for private packages.

The easiest way might be to just write your type declarations by hand in the .d.ts file instead of writing jsdoc comments. Otherwise, you'll need to find a way to generate those .d.ts files from the jsdoc annotations (maybe the TypeScript compiler can do this?) and integrate this into your rollup build

Code hinting (including type hint) in VSCode is provided by its "IntelliSense" feature.
As you may have guessed, IntelliSense for JavaScript is actually based on TypeScript (hence the usage of .d.ts files). But it is able to use JSDoc and inference to determine types within JavaScript code, without proper .ts files. That is how you currently use it in your source code.
As you have noticed, JavaScript built dependencies have accompanying type definitions (the .d.ts files), either "natively" provided by the module (and referenced in their package.json file "types" or "exports.types" field), or through DefinitelyTyped modules as @types/<original-module> (as mentioned in Bergi's question comment), which are automatically downloaded by VSCode.
The second case is there to enable describing JS libraries by external people, who may not have write permission on these libraries repository. It is indeed not your use case.
In the first case, these .d.ts files can be either:

generated automatically, usually from .ts files
manually edited to describe the JS files, in which we may not want to add type annotations (whether through TypeScript conversion or JSDoc annotations), or because these annotations are removed during build for publication: this sounds like your use case, where your JSDoc annotations are probably stripped during your Rollup build.

While the initial purpose of the package.json file "types" or "exports.types" field is indeed to reference the library .d.ts file with type definitions, as you figured out, you can reference the actual source code, and the JavaScript IntelliSense service is able to get its types as described at the beginning. While unconventional, there is actually nothing wrong with it (at least for the sake of JS IntelliSense) : you point a file that TypeScript can parse to derive its types.
Although you mention not being interested in that option, there is also the possibility to automatically generate the .d.ts file from JSDoc.

Thanks! Very helpful response that clairifies a lot for me.
